# average of calculated rank in tableau

Tags: aggregate, average, tableau-api, rank

I would like to calculate the average of calculated rank for each competitor variable. I have trouble finding a solution as calculated rank is aggregated value. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

It is the 2015_06 packaged file, and see "sheet 7".

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1PGq-fzDlKcWi03emxrQm1wdWs

Comment: there is no package, nor a link to download the workbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate the aggregated values in Tableau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763536/aggregate-the-aggregated-values-in-tableau)

Comment: How can I link a package here?

Comment: @user2192777 Host it on DropBox, Google Drive or something similar and share the link

Comment: added the link. Thanks!

Comment: @user2192777 no you just have to edit the permissions, so that people can actually access that file.

Comment: Can you not still open the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your workbook.
You need to do a change to your calculated field but then you can do it fairly easily with the table calculations.

Change the field `Prem Rank` to `Rank(sum([Premium]),'asc')`
Right click on it in the Marks section and make sure that "Compute Using" is set to "Table (Down)"

1. Create a calculated field with `WINDOW_AVG([Prem Rank])` (I called it `WINDOW_AVG([Prem Rank])`).
2. Drop it into the column shelf
3. Right click on AVG(rank) -> Edit Table Calculation -> choose "Compute using: Advanced"
4. Change the settings according to this picture:

[image]

5. Right click on AVG(rank) again and choose "Discrete"

The result will be a table like this:

[image]

I think that is what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for the help! It is very close. I wanted the average of each column, not the row.

Comment: Can I perhaps add a grand total that calculate the average of RankAverage?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PGq-fzDlKcWi03emxrQm1wdWs/view?usp=sharing 

I wanted the rank average to be only the average of "ALLSTATE". So the number should have been 1.5 ([2+1]/2), 2, 2 for each Tier....I am still having trouble how to fix this..

Comment: @John For the average of each column you just move the RankAverage to 'Columns' and change the table calc to 'Table Down' or so. I will check and update the answer. 
Is your last requirement to have only the average for ALLSTATE fullfilled with that? Because I don't really follow your calculation in the last comment

Comment: Yes Alex, I added the RankAverage to column but it is calculate the average across all other companies. I want the average of ALLSTATE on display. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @John But you do know that in this set up, the average of each column will be the amount of QuoteNo/2 (and rounded up) for each column? So in the table above, every column average is 4 (7 Quotes devided by 2 equals 3.5 - round that up and you have 4) So there is really no point of doing that

Comment: Sorry Alex, this file can better explain what I would like to accomplish. The rankaverage I am expecting is 1.5, 2, 2 for allstate respectively. Thanks!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1PGq-fzDlKcWlhmNEdCMjQ1WkU/view?usp=sharing